# How can I end a slur in multiple alternative endings in Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond, repeats, slurs

I'm trying to get lilypond to create a slur that ends in multiple alternative endings to a repeat.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
\relative c' {
  \repeat volta 2 {
    c d e f(
    \alternative {
      \volta 1 { g) a b c }
      \volta 2 { g) f e d }
    }
  }
}
```

This produces:

[image: Lilypond output]

I'd like to have the slur end in the second alternate ending as well, as shown by the hand-drawn red line. Is this possible?

With the above code I get a compiler warning "cannot end slur" on the `g)` in the second alternate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In single note cases you might use `\repeatTie`:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/writing-rhythms.html#ties

In more complex cases (multiple notes slurred under the volta) you can create a tie and move the left control point:

```
\relative c' {
  \repeat volta 2 {
    c d e f(
    \alternative {
      \volta 1 { g) a b c }
      \volta 2 { g\repeatTie f e d }
    }
  }
}

\relative c' {
  \repeat volta 2 {
    c d e f_(
    \alternative {
      \volta 1 { g a b) c }
      \volta 2 { \shape #'((-1.5 . -1) (0 . -0.6) (0 . 0) (0 . 0)) Slur g( f e) d }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw `\repeatTie` in the docs but figured it wouldn't work because this was a slur, not a tie. Guess I should have tried it.

Comment: @AndrewCooper `repeatTie` simply inserts a ”hanging“ tie ending at the note. So the tie part is mostly about the shape.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again.